# How prevalent is racism in the Inner Sphere?

Tags: battletech

Since the lore exists to justify a the near constant state of war in the Battletech universe, nationalism  seems to be quite common among the factions of the Inner Sphere. But how prevalent is racism in the setting?

I was especially thinking about holdover prejudices from real world history among the various ethnic groups within the larger factions.

Please tell me in the comments if this is an inappropriate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Racism seems to vary across factions of the Inner Sphere.

Justin Allard, a half-Capellan MechWarrior, experiences racism while training a unit of House Davion recruits:

> "I don't care that you called me a... Ah, how did you put it?"
>
> A smirk twisted the corners of Craon's mouth, and Justin felt his own anger leap up like a solar flare. "I believe I called you the halfwit whelp of a Capellan whore forced on a Davion noble to prevent a war."
>
> Justin studied the computer screen again and nodded. "Almost word for word. You must have practiced." *Since your early years, no doubt. Let's hope your racism has not warped your reason.*

- *Warrior: En Garde*

Later, Allard is shown to be hiding his knowledge of the Capellan language:

> "Code check: *Zhe jian fang tai xiao.* Authorization code: alpha x-ray tango bravo." [. . .] A sudden new though sent a chill up Justin's spine as he realized that if his code ever did become known, it would only confirm the bigoted opinions about him. *Stupid, Justin*, he thought. *Better change it after this exercise*.

- *Warrior: En Garde*

By contrast, Minobu Tetsuhara of the Draconis Combine is a black man who follows samurai code and tradition. This is not seen as unusual or worthy of comment by any in-canon source.

The Clans are, if not anti-racist, at least a pure meritocracy. Nicholas Kerensky specifically excluded old world biases from the Clan's criteria for military service:

> In creating the Clans, Nicholas wanted to break all pre-existing ties [. . .] Rigorous testing ensured only the best warriors were included in the new units, which Nicholas named for various predators of the worlds of the Star League in Exile. He used no other criteria: no gender bias, no cultural quotas, no racial restrictions.

- *The Clans: Warriors of Kerensky*